# Application Insights chart is not respecting query order in a shared dashboard

Tags: azure-application-insights, azure-data-explorer, kql

The query is actually pretty simple:

```
traces
| extend SdIds = customDimensions.SdIds
| where isnull(customDimensions.AmountOfBlobStorageLoadedRows) == false 
or isnull(customDimensions.AmountOfRowsAfterTransformation) == false
or isnull(customDimensions.AmountOfRowsIngestedToDW) == false
| summarize 
BlobReadSum=sum(toint(customDimensions.AmountOfBlobStorageLoadedRows)),
TransformationSum=sum(toint(customDimensions.AmountOfRowsAfterTransformation)),
SavedToDWSum=sum(toint(customDimensions.AmountOfRowsIngestedToDW)) 
by tostring(SdIds)
| order by BlobReadSum desc, TransformationSum desc, SavedToDWSum desc
| limit 10
```

The following picture shows the application insights log tool. Like expected, the biggest values appear first in the chart:

[image]

However, the picture below shows the output of the same query, using the same time range, published to a shared dashboard:

[image]

What happened to the order?
Is there any setting that may interfere on this?

Answer (score 0):

You could add `| sort tostring(SdIds)` after `| order` in the suffix of your query:

```
| order by BlobReadSum desc, TransformationSum desc, SavedToDWSum desc
| sort tostring(SdIds)
| limit 10
```

In azure log analytics dashboard parts there's an automatic sort for the x axis when its type is string.

You might notice that the chart sort in the dashboard would be just the opposite. In this case click "Open chart in Analytics" in the top right corner of your part, and change the desc/asc sort configuration of | sort tostring(SdIds) command.

Comment: I did what tou suggested and I have changed the "Sort results by TimeGenerated (Log Analytics) / timestamp (App Insights)" to OFF in the analytics, which was the only config I could find, but it still dont work.

Comment: I meant that you should sort the same column you choose to be your X-axis in the chart in the query, in your example query it should be tostring(sdIds)

Comment: I got that, but that is not what I want here. I want them in this order: "order by BlobReadSum desc, TransformationSum desc, SavedToDWSum desc" not sdIds order